# Count how many "commas" are in a line

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need a code to count how many commas there are in a richtextbox line. If there are 4 or more commas then do something, else delete line.

Comment: I wonder which answer is the most efficient.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: as of me - in such cases I would prefer to choose the most readable one: linq

Comment: @Cristian - if the line has less than say 1,000 commas, I don't think performance will be an issue with any of them. I personally think that @Jay's answer is the Rockinest!!!

Comment: Yes, in the case of a GUI application it doesn't matter if you save a couple of milliseconds. On the other hand in the case of a server processing a lot of messages, it would matter, so it would be good to have an efficient answer too, besides a readable/cool one. By the way, I found the LINQ version interesting and gave it +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's C#, but you could do something like this:

```
int count = 0;

foreach(char c in string)
{
    if(c == ',') count++;
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's the obligatory LINQ answer:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = yourString.Count(Function(ch) ch = ","c)
```

Comment: +1 - These expressions just look a whole lot cooler!!! and take up a whole lot less real estate.

Comment: However, just because you can't see the implementation doesn't mean it isn't costing you. In this case, not too bad; linear-time, which really can't be improved on for an "unordered" indexed collection like a string. However, there are some Linq one-liners that look very elegant but execute several orders of magnitude slower than an efficient iterative solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Dim str As String = "Count, the, commas,,, !"

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In str
        If c = "," Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Vote up Dan @ Demand's answer, this is just the VB.Net version.

Comment: You should have put a [link to Dan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756262/count-how-many-commas-are-in-a-line/3756292#3756292). LE: if you could...

Comment: I would have if I could (started the question with 49 rep, 1 under what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
string test = "abc,123,dfg";
int count = test.Split(',').length - 1;
```

sorry i'm a c# guy.  Here is vb.net (i think):

```
Dim test As String = "abc,123,dfg"
Dim count As Integer = test.Split(',').length - 1
```

Comment: it should be Length upper-case

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Count, the, commas,,, !";
var answer = str.Length - str.Replace(",", "").Length;
```

Comment: Technically speaking, the `Replace` will cause unnecessary shifts in memory.

Comment: @Josh Stodola: Yup, I've just posted "yet another possible way to do that"

Answer (score 1):

```
if( new RegEx(",").Match(s).Matches.Count > 4 ){
    //insert logic here
}
```

I'm doing this off the top of my head so don't kill me if it's not perfect code, but you get the gist of what i'm doing. You can leverage a regular expression to tell you exactly how many commas there are and to perform the required logic if the condition is met.

Comment: you've lost the source string

Comment: Point taken, I updated the example. My original point still stands.

Comment: No question would be complete without a RegEx solution.